# Centrally update multiple AWS Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating multiple (dozens) of lambda functions with identical code and only env vars changing. WHY? to create least privilege in accessing resources and in being accessed themselves.

I want to be able to centrally update the code for them, without redeploying every such lambda. I found that Lambda layers updates require redeployment of the lambdas to take effect.
I see though that I can also use containers, with the lambda pointing to an image registry (ECR) image. Are the images fetched dynamically at the Lambda invokation time (which would enable central updates) or packaged into the lambda resource at deployment (which would require redeployment jsut like layers)?

Answer (score 0):

[Found the relevant docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-images.html#configuration-images-update)

> After you deploy a container image to a function, the image is read-only. To update the function code, you must first deploy a new image version. Create a new image version, and then store the image in the Amazon ECR repository.

Seems that what I had in mind is prevented by design by AWS Lambda